# Create folder from Windows then access from Bash in Windows 10 WSL

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running Ubuntu from Windows.

When I create a folder from Windows called `newFolder` in the root directory `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\lxss\root\Newfolder` then from Bash when I run `ls` I don't see the new folder that was just created.

How can I fix this so that I can create folders and files from Windows then access them from Bash?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/1083962/windows-linux-subsystem-accessing-files-outside-of-ubuntu?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Update:

Since Windows 10 version 1903 it's possible to access Linux files from Windows with `\\wsl$\`. So you can run `explorer.exe .` from bash or enter `\\wsl$\` directly in Explorer's address bar

See [What’s new for WSL in Windows 10 version 1903?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/)

Again there's still the warning that you [must NOT access your Linux files via the AppData folder!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)

For older versions of Windows 10 see below

---

Linux files in WSL root file system are created specially with POSIX permissions stored in NTFS extended attributes. You can see that by running `fsutil file layout lxss\root` and notice the [`$EA` stream](https://flatcap.org/linux-ntfs/ntfs/attributes/ea.html) there. If you create the files directly from Windows you'll mess up things because win32 apps knows nothing about Linux and its file metadata

> The problem arises when, for example, you use a Windows app/tool to open, create and/or modify a file under your distro root: Since the file was created with a Windows tool, the file won't have any Linux file metadata (e.g. permissions, owner, access/update timestamps, etc.). Thus, to Linux, (which only receives Linux file metadata), ***the file may be reported as empty**, may not even exist, or may have some metadata, but that metadata may not reflect the file's details resulted in the file's contents being corrupted*.

Therefore MS has boldly warned that

> ## DO NOT, under ANY circumstances, create and/or modify Linux files using Windows apps, tools, scripts, consoles, etc.
>
> ## Creating/changing Linux files from Windows will likely result in data corruption and/or damage your Linux environment requiring you to uninstall & reinstall your distro!
>
> [Do not change Linux files using Windows apps and tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)

Files that are only relevant to Linux should be created only from WSL. If you want to create files that are accessible both systems then create them **outside the WSL root** and access from WSL via the mount point in `/mnt` like `/mnt/drive/path`

If you want to create files on Windows file systems but retain the case sensibility then use

```
fsutil file setCaseSensitiveInfo <directory name> enable
```

The flag can also be checked with `fsutil file queryCaseSensitiveInfo <directory name>`

See also [How to access linux/Ubuntu files from Windows 10 WSL?](https://superuser.com/q/1110974/241386)

Comment: Isn't the issue with accessing files from WSL in Windows EOL conversion? 
 If so, that can be avoided with a cross-platform text editor like [Atom](https://atom.io) or [VScode](https://code.visualstudio.com/), or a Windows coding editor like [NotePad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Comment: @JW0914 no. who talk about text files? Did you even read what I quoted? The issue is that any files created from Windows don't have Linux metadata and *may be reported as empty* (which is what the OP observed), *may not even exist, or may have some metadata, but that metadata may not reflect the file's details resulted in the file's contents being corrupted*. Regarding EOL then even [Notepad nowadays have the ability to open it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/05/08/extended-eol-in-notepad/) whereas Wordpad and IE can open them for decades

Comment: I overlooked your first quote block due to your second, thanks for pointing that out =]  As to _" Regarding EOL then even Notepad nowadays have the ability to open it whereas Wordpad and IE can open them for decades"_, opening yes, editing on Windows, while maintaining LF EOLs, no (although I think Notepad may finally have received that feature with it's most recent update).

Comment: @JW0914 Notepad does have ability to edit LF (and CR)-ending files, and it does [get a ton of new features](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/07/11/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17713/#3qoLMlQzTW01iKb1.97). Indeed not many people use it and it doesn't have many useful features, but see [Maintaining Notepad is not a full-time job, but it’s not an empty job either](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180521-00/?p=98795)

Answer (score 6):

You can not create folders in Ubuntu and access them from Windows. But you can do opposite.

You can access your Windows' drives at `/mnt`. If you do `ls /mnt` you will see all your drives. So /mnt/c is path of your C drive. Similarly `/mnt/c/Users/username/Desktop` can give you access to your desktop in Bash.

So just reach to your desired path using Bash and access windows files & folders. For more details on making quick access to your windows files, use symlinks, details can be [found here](https://superuser.com/a/1196469/245272)

Answer (score 2):

Invert your thinking: If you want to create files using Windows apps & tools, and access them from Bash, then create those files etc. in your Windows filesystem and access/copy them from Bash.

Here's an example of creating a file in PowerShell, then calling Bash to copy the created file into the home folder, and then calling bash to write the contents of the file:

```
PS C:\dev\temp> Set-Content ./hello.txt -Value "Hello, World!" -Encoding ASCII
PS C:\dev\temp> cat .\hello.txt
Hello, World!
PS C:\dev\temp> bash -c "cp /mnt/c/dev/temp/hello.txt ~/"
PS C:\dev\temp> bash -c "cat /mnt/c/dev/temp/hello.txt"
Hello, World!
```

HTH.