# SSH can't find id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssh, openssh, ssh-keys

`id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` are located in `K:\Batch\mySSH`, with script `K:\Batch\mySSH\runme.cmd` being called from Excel (via VBA), containing the following:

```bat
pushd %~dp0
  set home=%CD:~0,2%\Batch\mySSH
  %home%\ssh -v -o LogLevel=Verbose user@11.111.111.11 "do something"
popd
```

- `runme.cmd` output:

  ```bat
  OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.9.2

  debug1: Connecting to 11.111.111.11 [11.111.111.11] port 22.
  debug1: Connection established.
  debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\johnDoe/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
  ...
  debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
  debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\johnDoe/.ssh/id_rsa
  ...
  debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
  debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\johnDoe/.ssh/id_rsa
  ```

How do I ensure it looks for `K:\Batch\mySSH\.ssh\id_rsa`, instead of targeting `C:\Users\johnDoe\.ssh`?

Comment: And hence my question, how do I make it look for the key file in the folder of my choice.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the `-i` parameter is used to specify your identity file; for instance change:

- From:

  ```bat
  %home%\ssh -v -o LogLevel=Verbose user@11.111.111.11 "do something"
  ```

  To:

  ```bat
  %home%\ssh -v -o LogLevel=Verbose user@11.111.111.11 -i id_rsa "do something"
  ```

Comment: That doesn't work. It still looks for the file id_rsa in the folder C:\Users\johnDoe\.ssh\  . However, this file is located in K:\Batch\mySSH\.ssh\

Comment: Try and use the absolute path to your identity file, you might need to escape spaces with `\ ` if your path contains any. Hopefully this should fix your issue: `-i K:\Batch\mySSH\.ssh\id_rsa`.

Alternatively, consider storing your identity files inside of your user directory, inside of `.ssh`. This would be better practice than leaving your identity outside of the user protected directory structure.

Comment: I know that if I store the file in the user folder all works fine. I have tested that already. When using the option -i %home%\.ssh\id_rsa , I'm getting the issue: Permissions for 'K:\\Batch\\mySSH\\.ssh\\id_rsa' are too open.

Comment: So the answer works. For the answer to your new problem, see https://superuser.com/q/1296024/213663