# Username mapped to some windows SID `S-1-5-21-...`, how to fix that?

Tags: windows, ssh, permissions, microsoft-account

First a short introduction what I was trying to do and how my issue showed up.

When i configure a ssh hosts in `.ssh/config` I have the issue that the permissions seem to be wrong on the config-file such that I get the error message `Bad owner or permissions on C:\\Users\\My Name/.ssh/config` when i try to use `ssh` with a config-file present.

I already tried everything mentioned in this post: [Windows SSH: Permissions for 'private-key' are too open](https://superuser.com/questions/1296024/windows-ssh-permissions-for-private-key-are-too-open)

Nothing worked. When I tried the tip of using the following commands

```
icacls config /inheritance:r
icacls config /grant:r "%username%":"(R)"
```

to remove all permissions beside mine, I lost access to the file myself and instead of my username some `S-1-5-21-...` shows up in the file permissions. My guess is that this is the root cause of the ssh issues I was seeing previously.

So %Username% (which expands to my real username) seems to be mapped to some spurious SID . Does anybody have any clue why this is so and how I can fix it?

One thing I did previously was logging into a windows account once without knowing that is would break my local user. So I immediately undid this and reverted to a local user. The only thing left from this experiment is that the user folder is still has my full name an not the name of the local user.

Comment: Most likely the shown SID belongs to your account just for an unknown reason Windows has stopped resolving it to your user name. Is it possible that you had deleted and recreated your user account?

Comment: Why not delete the file and recreate it with default permissions, rather than trying to fix it?

Comment: @Robert: Well kind of as I said, I accidentally converted the local account to the windows account. I assume that strange things happened then with the identity

Comment: @harrymc I recreated the file many times...

Comment: what I notices is that with a new user account everything works, something is broken with the current user...

Comment: Some corruption is very hard to analyze. I would suggest moving over to the new account.