# How to set 600 permission on a .pem file in w10?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, amazon-web-services, icacls

I am unable to change permissions to 600 on an AWS .pem file.

- Note that "inherited permissions" were turned off in all efforts, and owner was set properly.

1. Tried using this guide with File Explorer:
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264595/windows-chmod-600
2. Tried using this guide with PowerShell as Admin, and ICACLS:
   [Windows SSH: Permissions for 'private-key' are too open](https://superuser.com/questions/1296024/windows-ssh-permissions-for-private-key-are-too-open)
3. Tried good ole' fashioned:
    chmod 600 with Git Bash. ng.
4. I followed the instructions in this vid (skip to 5:17):
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZcC4Eq0a5Mw
5. I've also tried resetting the file in an Admin Windows Powershell with:

> icacls .\key.pem /T/ Q/ /C /RESET

The file stubbornly remains at permissions 644, or  rw-r--r--. Since AWS requires 600 on a .pem file, this prevents me from ssh'ing into my instance.

Nothing is working! Why is this stuck? Why can't I change these permissions? Such a simple thing hanging me up and eating up time... frustrating. Ty.

Answer (score 1):

I got in. For posterity, here's what was happening. It was a two-part problem.

1. I am using Git Bash. On an `ls -al` command, the permissions were shown as `rw-r--r--`. When viewed in Windows Properties, they were set correctly.
2. The username on the remote box was not properly set up for `ssh`

To discover this, I logged in using tried from my Mac, setting the permissions in a linux-style. There I found that the username was not set up. Then I went back to windows and tried again, despite the permissions appearing wrong in Git bash... and it worked.

Comment: I'm struggling with this too, I might have to install a different ssh client. I can't understand how after all these years AWS doesn't put Windows instructions there.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer of Chao](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610256/chmod-wsl-bash-doesnt-work) helped me, because I have WSL installed on my Windows 10.

In WSL (Ubuntu on Windows) I opened a text editor with `sudo` and created the file `/etc/wsl.conf` with text in it:

```
[automount]
options = "metadata"
```

Then rebooted my Windows.

Now I am able to edit file permissions in WSL: `chmod 0600` now works!