# "WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!" - can not sign in to VPS Ubuntu-account from local Windows 10 computer

Tags: windows-10, ssh, powershell, vps, icacls

Following [this authoritative article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-ubuntu-20-04), I created the SSH keys at Windows local PC and copied them to VPS (this article does not cover the Windows case, but I found appropriate solution).

Now, when I trying to sign in to VPS via SSH:

```
ssh -i "C:\Users\Me\.ssh\MyWebApp.pub" non_root_admin@160.XXX.XX.XXX
```

I get the error:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions for 'C:\\Users\\Me\\.ssh\\MyWebApp.pub' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "C:\\Users\\Me\\.ssh\\MyWebApp.pub": bad permissions
non_root_admin@160.XXX.XX.XXX's password:
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

In this stage, I already have at least 2 questions:

1. The key has been created in specific user's directory (for example, **Me**). If so, what "accessible by others" means?
2. It was told what **private** key is unprotected while **.pub** refers to public one.

Please explain theese moments to excause this topics.
Still not understanting above moments, I googled [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/1470382):

```
Icacls <file name> /Inheritance:r
Icacls <file name> /Grant:r "%Username%":"(R)"
```

As far as I understood the concept is deny all interations with this keys for all users and the give the permissions to currect users only.

The second command will cause other error; the correct syntax will be:

```
Icacls <file name> /Grant:r "$Username":"(R)"
```

Although PowerShell will report about successfull completion, if to try sign in again, "UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!" warning still will be.

The version of Ubuntu in VPS is 20.04.

Comment: You need to set the file permissions of your key so that whatever user will be using the key is the only user that has permissions to it.  If you are unfamiliar with Bash syntax you should just use the properties window. [Sadly, your question, is a duplicate of the question you linked to.](https://superuser.com/questions/1296024/windows-ssh-permissions-for-private-key-are-too-open?noredirect=1&lq=1)